# Programmatically determine if a named range is scoped to a workbook

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I am attempting what I thought would be a fairly simple vba statement to test whether a named range is scoped to a workbook or a specific sheet.

---

As a test, I have created a new Excel document and added in 6 named ranges. Here is how they are layed out in the *Name Manager*:

```
 Name         |   Refers To          |   Scope
 -------------+----------------------+-----------
 rng_Local01  |   =Sheet1!$A$2:$A$16 |   Sheet1
 rng_Local02  |   =Sheet1!$C$2:$C$16 |   Sheet1
 rng_Local03  |   =Sheet1!$E$2:$E$16 |   Sheet1
 rng_Global01 |   =Sheet1!$B$2:$B$16 |   Workbook
 rng_Global02 |   =Sheet1!$D$2:$D$16 |   Workbook
 rng_Global03 |   =Sheet1!$F$2:$F$16 |   Workbook
```

---

I would expect that running:

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
    If ThisWorkbook.Names(i).WorkbookParameter Then Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
Next i
```

would result in the three `Workbook` scoped named ranges to be logged, however, nothing happens. There is no error. The `.Names(i).WorkbookParameter` evaluates to `False` on **ALL** of the named ranges and I am not sure why.

---

Looking through the `Name` object in the VBA help I came across `ValidWorkbookParameter` which looks like the *ReadOnly* cousin of `WorkbookParameter`, however using that method does NOT make any difference.

I have also tried explicitly setting `ThisWorkbook.Names(i).WorkbookParameter = True`, however this results in an error:

> "Invalid procedure call or argument"

Despite the fact that `WorkbookParameter` is listed as being *Read/Write*

---

Can anyone shed any light onto why this isn't working as I'm expecting it too? Have I misunderstood how `Name.WorkbookParameter` is supposed to work? Is anyone able to get this to run successfully?

Comment: Thanks for the very usable solutions guys... I am still curious as to the behavior of the `WorkbookParameter` and `ValidWorkbookParameter` properties of the `Name` object in VBA. In my mind, those properties aren't working *as advertised*.

Comment: Not sure exactly what WorkbookParameter is but suspect its for Excel Services in Sharepoint and not for client Excel

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the Parent property:

```
Sub Global_Local_names()
    Dim oNm As Name
    For Each oNm In Names
        If TypeOf oNm.Parent Is Worksheet Then
            Debug.Print oNm.Name & " is local to " & oNm.Parent.Name
        Else
            Debug.Print oNm.Name & " is global to " & oNm.Parent.Name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution... I had not thought of using the `Parent` property. I marked this one as the answer since it most directly deals with whether the named range belongs to the workbook or a sheet.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't manage to make the WorkbookParameter work but I found a workaround:

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Names.Count
    If UBound(Split(ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name, "!")) > 0 Then Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Names(i).Name
Next i
```

The name of the *local* Named Range (i.e. scope to a sheet only) is formatted this way: `Sheet1!NamedRange` whereas the name of the *global* Named Range is formatted: `NamedRange`.

Thus, you can split on the `!` and check the length of the array.

Comment: I like the creative solution using `Split`