# VBA Only Unhide Workbook Scope Named Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I have a workbook with many named ranges (both sheet and workbook scope) which are all hidden. I have a macro that can unhide all of the name ranges but I only want to unhide the workbook scope named ranges, NOT all the sheet scope ranges. Can someone please help me with my code below?

Thanks.

```
Sub Unhide_All_Ranges()

Dim xName As Name

For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Name
    xName.Visible = True
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656793/programmatically-determine-if-a-named-range-is-scoped-to-a-workbook)?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @BigBen